# Change the color of Bootstrap 4 dropdown items when they are clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently playing around with Bootstrap, and was testing the following code for animated dropdown navbars. Please see the following snippet:

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: #3d155f;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* Sticky Footer Classes */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

/* Dropdown Menu Animation for Bootstrap Navbar by Startbootstrap.com - https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/animated-navbar-dropdown/ */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .animate {
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: transform;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-name: slideIn;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-11/css/all.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start" href="#">Title</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Menu
                        </a>
            <!-- Here's the magic. Add the .animate and .slide-in classes to your .dropdown-menu and you're all set! -->
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right animate slideIn" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- main body -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="sidebar" class="row col-md-4 ml-0 py-3 px-3 justify-content-center">
        <div class="row col-12">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio aliquam sequi, explicabo doloremque esse maiores rerum natus recusandae repellat amet porro modi saepe ratione minima voluptas. Assumenda mollitia libero animi pariatur officiis iste odio
          nihil repellat neque at, optio veritatis esse repudiandae enim alias sed eaque vero a illo expedita deserunt dolor nemo laudantium. Suscipit pariatur quaerat exercitationem saepe aut?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="row col-md-8 ml-0 py-3 pl-5 align-items-center justify-content-center order-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime tempore quibusdam quia facere magnam ipsa dolorum fuga natus, commodi enim repudiandae temporibus modi eius obcaecati explicabo tempora sunt officia. Id inventore hic unde ipsam sit amet
        eveniet, provident quisquam, harum est optio nobis odit aspernatur suscipit dolor dolorum eligendi quis. Unde, modi eligendi enim pariatur voluptatibus odit nobis atque numquam consequuntur temporibus quaerat minus voluptas molestiae accusamus,
        et ea quis ab facilis aperiam dolore. Ipsum sed officiis quos placeat facilis, id esse aliquam eaque quisquam ad eius! Repudiandae dolorum quos modi amet accusamus corporis aliquam laboriosam soluta. Hic, incidunt ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <small>Copyright &copy; Your Name Here</small>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I change the color that appears on click for elements inside the dropdown menu? My guess is that I need to add a `:click` parameter somewhere in the CSS.

Comment: you want to change color of the dropdown menu on that button click ? is that  what you mean ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX - Sorry if not clear. On clicking 'Link 1' it currently defaults to the traditional Bootstrap blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the DOM on the element in the menu you can see the rule you need to override is the `background-color` on `.dropdown-item:active`. To do that, simply make the selector more specific in your own CSS code, for example by including the `.navbar`:

```
.navbar .dropdown-item:active {
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: #3d155f;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  padding-left: 30px;
}


/* Sticky Footer Classes */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}


/* Dropdown Menu Animation for Bootstrap Navbar by Startbootstrap.com - https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/animated-navbar-dropdown/ */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .animate {
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0rem);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: transform;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-name: slideIn;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item:active {
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-11/css/all.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-start" href="#">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right animate slideIn" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- main body -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sidebar" class="row col-md-4 ml-0 py-3 px-3 justify-content-center">
      <div class="row col-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio aliquam sequi, explicabo doloremque esse maiores rerum natus recusandae repellat amet porro modi saepe ratione minima voluptas. Assumenda mollitia libero animi pariatur officiis iste odio
        nihil repellat neque at, optio veritatis esse repudiandae enim alias sed eaque vero a illo expedita deserunt dolor nemo laudantium. Suscipit pariatur quaerat exercitationem saepe aut?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row col-md-8 ml-0 py-3 pl-5 align-items-center justify-content-center order-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime tempore quibusdam quia facere magnam ipsa dolorum fuga natus, commodi enim repudiandae temporibus modi eius obcaecati explicabo tempora sunt officia. Id inventore hic unde ipsam sit amet
      eveniet, provident quisquam, harum est optio nobis odit aspernatur suscipit dolor dolorum eligendi quis. Unde, modi eligendi enim pariatur voluptatibus odit nobis atque numquam consequuntur temporibus quaerat minus voluptas molestiae accusamus,
      et ea quis ab facilis aperiam dolore. Ipsum sed officiis quos placeat facilis, id esse aliquam eaque quisquam ad eius! Repudiandae dolorum quos modi amet accusamus corporis aliquam laboriosam soluta. Hic, incidunt ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <small>Copyright &copy; Your Name Here</small>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Works a treat. Thanks - will mark as correct in a few minutes.